# Calculating double integral with polar coordinates

Tags: integration

Can anyone help me with this double integral? I think I solved and I want to know if i'm correct. My result is π/2.

$$\iint_R \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dxdy$$ where 
$\ R= \{(x,y)| x\le0,y\ge0 ,  1\le x^2+y^2\le 2\}$

Comment: $\displaystyle=\int_1^2\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac1r\ r\mathrm dr\mathrm d\theta=\frac\pi2$

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle=\int_1^2\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}\frac1r\ r\ \mathrm dr\ \mathrm d\theta=\frac\pi2$

Note that the transformation from Cartesian to Polar is $\mathrm dx\ \mathrm dy=r\ \mathrm dr\ \mathrm d\theta$.

Comment: Exactly what i did. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the radius ranges from $1$ to $\sqrt{2}$. So, we have $$\int_1^\sqrt{2}\int_\frac{\pi}{2}^\pi\frac{1}{r}rd\theta dr=\frac{\pi}{2}\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right).$$

Comment: Wow, I never spotted that.